# Simple kafka stream does not fill the destination topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a bit of code that reads data from a kafka topic and after processing the data with some filters send the data to another topic.

## Main class

```java
public class UserMain {

    static Properties properties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        properties = configProperties();

        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = watchForUserUpdate(builder);

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), properties);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));
    }

    private static StreamsBuilder watchForUserUpdate(StreamsBuilder builder){
        UserUpdateListener userUpdateListener = new UserUpdateListener(builder);
        userUpdateListener.start();
        return builder;
    }

    private static Properties configProperties(){

        Properties streamProperties = new Properties();

        //add some static stuff, skimmed for clarity

        return streamProperties;

    }
```

## UserUpdateListener class

```java
 private StreamsBuilder builder;

    public UserUpdateListener(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    public void start(){
        builder.stream("mysql.company.users",
                Consumed.with(UserSerde.getGenericKeySerde(), UserSerde.getEnvelopeSerde()))
                .filter((key,value) -> isUserUpdated(value))
                .filter((key,value) -> isUserCustomer(value.getAfter().getId()))
                .to("kafka-consumer.user.update");
    }
```

I have put som logs in both isUserUpdate and isUserCustomer methods and in many cases they both return true. Plus even without the filters the "kafka-consumer.user.update" topic still doesn't get filled. I have to point out that I have the exact same code in another application with some different topics and logics and despite being mutlithreaded it works like a charm.

the stream is receiving events and even I checked the payload of the event in both filter methods

Comment: Maybe you have to specify serdes to use in to() method with Produced.with(UserSerde.getGenericKeySerde(), UserSerde.getEnvelopeSerde())

Comment: @firegloves I have tried that too, plus almost the exact same code is running successfully as another app right now!

Comment: If you are not receiving errors maybe it is writing and you have problems on consuming?

Comment: @firegloves I used the kafka console consumer for checking, the topic is empty.

Comment: Can you share the Kafka properties you're using? Might help

Comment: Can You also try to consume them without your specific serdes ( and use  default byte arrays serdes), just to be sure it's not your serdes in cause?

Comment: Can you describe the topology (`streamsBuilder.build()`) and edit your question with the output? Can you also use `peek` to see if the topology gets any records?

Comment: @Hessam, for debug purpose you can add printing operation: `builder.stream("mysql.company.users",
                Consumed.with(UserSerde.getGenericKeySerde(), UserSerde.getEnvelopeSerde()))
                .filter((key,value) -> isUserUpdated(value))
                .filter((key,value) -> isUserCustomer(value.getAfter().getId()))
                .print(Printed.toSysOut[GenericKey, Envelope])`

Comment: Have you checked you have messages arriving in your source topic: "mysql.company.users" and the current offset of this stream consumer in the offset topic?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I used peek and everything is working fine.

Comment: @wardziniak I used peek and checked message payloads too. Everything looks normal.

Comment: @groo Yes, I used peek for debugging. Plus the source topic is provided by kafka connect and gets filled by binlog changes. Nothing I have done about it.

Comment: @Yannick Sorry missed your comment. What kind of properties shall I share?

Comment: All the Kafka properties of your consumer, things like isolated_level, auto_commit etc..